# How to understand that a user gets database access in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been tasked with auditing security on my SQL Server. But, when I look at a login in SQL Server Management Studio, I don't see a checkbox beside the master db for that login. How can I determine what databases a login has access to?

Comment: In SQL management studio, UserMapping of Login Properties will show mapping of a login to each database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a login match up to a user in this manner, then the login has access to the database.

```
SELECT sp.name AS 'Login', dp.name AS 'User' 
FROM sys.database_principals dp 
  JOIN sys.server_principals sp 
    ON dp.sid = sp.sid 
ORDER BY sp.name, dp.name;
```

you can do it in SQL Server 2005/2008

Answer (score 2):

ther is a useful system store procedure to list all mapping user of SQL login account.

Syntax:

```
sp_msloginmappings @Loginname , @Flags
```

> @loginname: the login account name, If loginname is not specified, results are returned for the login account(current login name)
>
> @Flags: value can be 0 and 1, by default 0. 0 means show mapping user in all databases. 1 indicates how mapping user in **current
>   database context**.

e.g
here is sample:

```
sp_msloginmappings 'sa'
show mapping user account info in all databases for login account 'sa'

sp_msloginmappings 'sa', 1
show mapping user account info in current databases context for login account 'sa'
```